# how to access a database using toad

Tags: database, oracle, toad

I have a database server with ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and there is a natting ip to it. 
When I am trying to access the Oracle database server via toad using the natting ip, I am getting TNS timeout error.

Whenever, I go and access it from the unix server (The DB server is installed in unix system), I am able to access it.

The database is properly configured and is working from another ips. But, not from my ip.

This problem I am facing from both database on unix and linux server

Comment: Before trying to access the db using Toad, you should check if you have access at all to the database. add the database to your tnsnames.ora file, and then run `tnsping <the service name appearing in tnsnames.ora>`, if this command manages to reach the DB, you can proceed to connect with Toad.

Comment: telnet the port of your database from your local machine (from where you are trying to access the database) for example telnet server_name 1521 . 1521 being your database port number

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to use a NAT address.  NAT is a way for a system to "hide" behind another IP address.  So the NAT address is never known by other systems. In order for a server process to be contacted by a client, the client has to know the IP address of the server, and by definition the client cannot know a NAT address.

Comment: I dont use tnsnames.ora. I try to directly connect using Direct IP ? 
Is there any location in $ORACLE_HOME ??

Comment: @EdStevens : But, I have other database, which I can connect using NAT IP

Comment: perhaps you are using the wrong terminology, but you simply cannot reach a NAT address from another machine.  I just now tried again to make sure I wasn't missing anything.  I have a linux vm running under VitualBox. It has two nics.  One configured NAT and has a dhcp address, the other is hostonly and has a fixed address.  I cannot ping the NAT adapter from outside of the vm itself.  Which, given what NAT is all about, is exactly what I'd expect.  Perhaps you should explain in more detail, with industry standard terms.